# Internal Server Error when trying to check url

Tags: php

I'm trying to check the string after the last trailing slash in my URL.

My code is as follows:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$data = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);

if($data == "dashboard") {
      require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/cp/dashboard_view.php';
} else {
      echo $data;
}
```

Once I go to `http://MYURL/dashboard/in` it should show `in` as the `$data`. Instead it gives me a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use explode() function to break the string... .Or else $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] shall give you the data after the host name...

But for the data after the last `'/'` explode function will work the best.. 
This will work.

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$x = explode('/',$url);
$data = $x[sizeof($x)-1];
echo $data;
```

Comment: Still the same 500 error. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: I ain't getting that error in your code as well... Try to comment the if statement completely.. I suspect its because of that require statement.

Comment: I need the if statement to check the `$data`. EDIT: If I comment out the `require` it still throws the error

Comment: Oh certainly... just comment it to check for debugging purpose... because i suspect the error to be somewhere else.. and not in this codesnippet you posted as well..

Comment: It shows the `$data` perfectly fine. It just doesn't work with an if statement?

Comment: I guess the error lies in your       require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/cp/dashboard_view.php';

Comment: Like I said, if I comment out the `require_once` it still throws the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114929/discussion-between-tirthraj-barot-and-chris).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

You need to join

```
http:// string with $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] and then $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] using .(dot).
```